# Repeating "to" as infinitive marker and preposition

Tags: prepositions, repetition

> Permission is hereby granted to all parties to copy and distribute
> verbatim copies of this license document provided that the copy of the
> license document remains completely unaltered.

Is "to all parties to" correct? How can I phrase it instead?

Comment: It's fine. I'm pleased to see that you recognise the second "to" as an infinitival marker (not a preposition) and not part of the verbs, which are just "copy" and "distribute".

Comment: *verbatim* = "completely unaltered" (with respect to the wording) so you could eliminate the proviso clause, unless by "copy" you mean "photocopy" and are expecting fonts and font-stylings (bold, italics, font-sizes) to remain intact as well.

Comment: @TimR In a linguistic sense I would completely agree with you but legal language demands you to be explicit

Comment: *verbatim* has a precise meaning.  "unaltered", on the other hand, is vague especially when it comes to a "copy" -- whatever that might mean  nowadays: electronic form in plain text? photocopy of the original? And in fact, adding that proviso suggests that "unaltered" means something other than or in addition to "verbatim". What other kinds of alterations are meant to be excluded? Could the license be distributed in a tiny font, or in a pale gray font against a pale gray background, as websites sometimes do with Terms of Service, to make them virtually illegible?

Comment: @TimR I see your point, I have opted to remove "verbatim" since I would like to keep the more legal suited clause as so:

"Permission is hereby granted to all parties to
copy and distribute copies of this license document provided that
the contents of the copy of the license document remains completely unaltered
without exception in any and all circumstances."


(Redundancy is intentional) By "copy" I mean a digital "copy". I have included "contents of the copy of the..." to mitigate your last point

Comment: I would add "**in any and all respects** and in any and all circumstances"    Down to the character encoding? :-)

Comment: @TimR Nope, just the worlds, newlines, spaces, characters, structure, format etc should remain the same. how the contents are presented, don't care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 'permission is granted **to** all parties **to** copy...', the first 'to' is a necessary preposition after the verb 'granted'; the second is a necessary part of the infinitive of the verb 'to copy'. You need both, the phrasing is correct, and does not need to be altered.